# Visualize one out of many components in igraph

Tags: r, visualization, igraph

Using the R igraph package, I have an undirected graph with the following edges:

`A--B`, `B--C`, `A--C`, `C--D`, `E--F` & `G--H`

The `plot()` function plots the entire network, but I want to visualize only the connected component that contains the node `A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `components` to compute the components and `induced_subgraph` to grab the nodes in A's component:

```
plot(induced_subgraph(G, with(components(G), membership == membership["A"])))
```

[image]

Data:

```
library(igraph)
G <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(X=c("A", "B", "A", "C", "E", "G"),
                                 Y=c("B", "C", "C", "D", "F", "H")),
                      directed=F)
```